# Move sign in to bottom in my top links

Tags: magento2, toplinks

I want my top links in the order like:

1. My Account
2. My Wishlist
3. My Orders
4. Sign In

But I am getting like:

1. My Account
2. My Wishlist
3. Sign In
4. My Orders

Below is my code:

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link" before="my-account-link"
               template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml"/>

        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link" after="authorization-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link-top" after="my-account-link" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Orders</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/222717/3368

Comment: it didn't worked

Comment: can you past your latest code  here?

Comment: Above is my latest code

Comment: Did you check answer of https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/223927/3368

Comment: Any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code instead of yours:

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Orders</argument>
            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link" after="customer-account-navigation-orders-link-top"
           template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Flush the cache and test.

Comment: It is not working. Any new solution? I can't able to reorder the links in the dropdown.

Comment: Then Magento core top links are not working on your theme. It might handled through different way or code.

Comment: It works on all pages except customer account pages. Any thoughts why?