# Magento 2.4.3 User account Menu options

Tags: navigation, magento2.4.3, user-account

I have I have Magento 2.4.3 with Claue 2 theme installed on it, dont see any file in theme directory which is defining the links provided under User account menu dropdown as given in screenshot here

[image]

I want to change sequence of the links keeping Sign Out at the end and also want to add My Cart link to this, couldn't find a templet file for this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

let's search in file Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml or file Magento_Custommer/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="links.header">

or

<referenceBlock name="header.links">

or

<referenceBlock name="top.links">
```

You can read instructions for adding a simple link here to find a solution to the problem
https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/how-to-add-custom-link-in-header-links-and-top-links-in-magento-2/

[Reorder Top Links](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222717/reorder-top-links)

use **sortOrder** to change the position of the links you want